# Vertical Line chart with ChartJS

Tags: chart.js

I have a problem with the ChartJS API in order that I need to paint a Line graphic, but lines should be painted vertically instead of horizontally.

The only response I can found is to draw static vertical lines in a "standard" horizontal line chart, but that's not the feature I need.

I suppose that ChartJS should hace any graphic type or options in [Line](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) graphic type to do this, but I don't see it.

Using `"chart.js": "2.9.3"`

I need something like this:
[image]

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the beta (version 3) of Chart.js you can set the property `indexAxis` to y in your options object to get the desired behaviour

Example:

```
options: {
  indexAxis: 'y'
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it, using *chart.js: 2.9.3*

Comment: Dont think its possible in an easy way without creating your own chart. They have a variant for horizontal bars but havent seen any vertical lines build in.

Comment: I saw the github repo.

Thanks for answer! I'll check how to do it, and wait for the v3 release!